# handlers for specific Exception

Tags: python, django

I have created a specific Exception class

```
class myException(Exception):
    ...
```

and I raise the exception on some specific view

In django already exist a way to handle some exception (like Http404, Http403....) in urls.py

```
handler404 = 'myViews.error.not_found'
```

What I'd like to do is to handle myException, in order to redirect to another view.

How can I do that ?

Comment: write your own handler? it's just a function

Comment: ok, but where should I put this function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by writing and registering a custom [Django middleware class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) for your project.

In the middleware's [`process_exception`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception) method, check for the exception you are interested in and generate an appropriate HttpResponse:

```
def process_exception(self, request, exception):
    if isinstance(exception, myException):
        return http.HttpResponse("myException raised")
    else:
        # Perform standard error handling for other exceptions:
        return None
```